# Calculating server bandwidth and ssd reading speed

Tags: nginx, bandwidth, video-streaming

We have about 6tb of content, about 500mb per mp4 file and a bitrate of 1200 where we would need to stream to about 5000 concurrent users.
I'm not very experienced on network engineering so i have some doubts about our server needs.

To support 5000 online users we planed something like this server:

- 2xE5-2620v3

  64gb ram

  5x2tb SSD's samsung 860 qvo in raid 0

  5gbps unmetered bandwidth

Question is, since the ssd's reading speed is about 500mbps, would the reading speed max out at 500 users downloading at 1mbps? 
How could i calculate a server to support 5000 users streaming at the same time at 1mbps? Are this specs ok?
Btw, we use centos 7 and nginx for delivery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: Capacity planning: off topic.

Comment: The answer to your question depends enormously on what software is involved between the hardware and the users.

Answer (score 0):

Reading speed would probably Max out much higher then 500 users Because you are using RAID0 you can get up to 5 times the disk performance. (Note up to). This is because data is pulled off all disks simultaneously.

You also need to realize that a megabyte works out to about 8 times as much as a megabit (ignoring  packet overhead etc).

You also have caching - if multiple people look at a popular video at about the same time it will be in memory so won't need to be pulled from disk.

It is certainly likely that your system could provide simultaneous access to 500 people, with the bottleneck being the bandwidth to the server. No guarantee though.